# C# and .NET language: Replacing use of C Macro

Tags: c#, .net, language-features

I'm new in .Net development, and I'm looking for some advices.

I've some piece of code which throw some exceptions. These exception are thrown if my database is down for example. I want to let users have the capability to retry the executed code if failed.

Here my initial code :

```
executeRequest();
```

What I've thinked in C-style (but working anyway in C#):

```
do
{
    try
    {
        executeRequest();
        return;
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        ErrorMessagesUtils.ShowTaskErrorMessage(exception);
    }
} while (MessageBox.Show("Failed : Retry ?", "Error",
                         MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                         MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes);
```

It's working but it's really annoying to reproduce it with other methods. I want to use with *executeRequest* but **not only**.

If I was coding in C, I'll use `#define ASK_USER_TO_RETRY(funcname) ...code...`. But in C#, I've not found a way to reuse a piece of code in this manner. Some thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create method, which accepts delegate (method to be executed):

```
public void Execute(Action action)
{
    do
    {
        try
        {
            action();
            return;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            ErrorMessagesUtils.ShowTaskErrorMessage(exception);
        }
    } while (MessageBox.Show("Failed : Retry ?", "Error",
                 MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                 MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes);
}
```

Usage:

```
Execute(executeRequest);
```

Comment: I would do it in the same way. Here you can read more about delegates (it's something like pointer to a method in C): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171(v=vs.80).aspx and after it you can read about lambda expressions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

Comment: Dammit, you beat me to it by about thirty seconds :)

Comment: BTW if you need to execute some method with parameters, you do this:
Execute(delegate { SomethingWithParam(param1, param2); });

Comment: Answers assumed I have not other choices to define one delegate by action? This part is annoying when having a lot of different arguments and a lot of different methods :'(

Comment: You can use lambda expressions to call different methods via Execute: Execute(() => executeRequest(arg1)), Execute(() => executeRequest(arg1, arg2)) etc.

Comment: I misunderstood because you've missed definition of "Action" and your "BTW" comment :-)

Comment: Action is delegate from Framework 3.5 :)
System.Core.Action, if you are using Framework 2.0 - you can create void() delegate on your own. And, of course, you can use lambda notation, if you like it :)

Answer (score 1):

It is always a pretty sad sight to watch a user banging away at a retry button without ever getting anywhere.  They keep it up for a while too, hoping for a miracle.  They'll switch the mouse to the left hand after half a minute of it.

The generic problem with this is that they'll blame *you* for the problem.  Even though you have nothing to do with it and cannot do anything at all to solve the problem.  After all, it was *you* that promised that a retry would make sense.  They'll quickly lose confidence in you as a programmer and your product as being usable and worth their money.  Don't do this unless you *actually* have a way in your code to execute a different strategy.  That's quite rare.

Comment: You are right, in a design point of view, it's not a good way to let the user retrying until the death. I've got the point :)

Answer (score 0):

Even in C using a macro for this maybe a bad idea.  As you know, with the pre-processor you don't even see what the compiler sees.  I'd assume a function pointer would be a better fit in that scenario.

So, as others have mentioned, in C# function pointers are replaced with delegates.  You can think of them as *type-safe function pointers* if you will.

I would recommend [Pro C# 2010 and the .NET 4 Platform](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430225491) and [C# Language Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx)